# ¿como montar un servidor publico con postgres gratis?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, servidor, redes

Debo trabajar desde dos lugares distintos con una misma base de datos, al estar en etapa de desarrollo necesito algo **libre** (gratis). Donde pueda montar una base de datos potgresql y acceder a ella desde cualquier lugar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te refieres a acceso remoto a alguna base de datos postgres y que sea gratis hay varias opciones, aquí te dejo algunos links:

https://www.heroku.com/postgres

https://www.heliohost.org/